# How to properly setup LFS supported git home server

Tags: git, git-lfs

So I need a LFS supported git home server for a game project. However I've run into multiple issues trying to do this and googling for hours without a satisfying answer on what is happening. I'll start by introducing my server implementation and the issues I've had with it.

1. I've installed an Ubuntu VM to act as the git server. I enabled ssh login and port-forwarded it so it can be accessed by our friend group outside my network. I have tested that the server is accessible to login from both inside and outside my network via SSH.
2. I installed git on the server, set up a user for it, initialized a bare repository and configured SSH following [these](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) instructions.
3. I installed git-lfs on the server via apt and enabled it on the repository I initiated with

```
git lfs install
```

running the command

```
git lfs env
```

gives me the following information [image: git lfs env output]

4. I clone the project on my PC and enable lfs on it with the install command. Then I create an UE5 project inside the git folder, add all the file types  I want to track via

```
git lfs track "*.*filetype*"
```

Then I make a commit and push it netting me this error [image: lfs lock error]

I disable the locking as instructed by the error, and make another push netting me this error [image]

Now I don't know how to proceed. What am I doing wrong? Troubleshooting this is a nuisance since the repo gets bricked after an error and I need to reset it.

I checked all the posts I could find here but they either lack answers or include third party stuff like BitKraken, which I am not using. I am not really interested in a premade server implementation for learning reasons, unless setting this up is unnecessary complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out. The problem is that ubuntu and debian repositories link to an extremely old version of git-lfs, which does not support pure ssh protocol transfer of files. You HAVE TO use either homebrew package manager to install git-lfs or install manually from a package on git-lfs' github page.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/api/server-discovery.md#ssh) mentions:

> If Git LFS detects an SSH remote, it will run the `git-lfs-authenticate` command.
> This allows supporting Git servers to give the Git LFS client alternative authentication so the user does not have to setup a git credential helper.
>
> Git LFS runs the following command:
>
> ```
> $ ssh [{user}@]{server} git-lfs-authenticate {path} {operation}
> ```
>
> - The `user`, `server`, and `path` properties are taken from the SSH remote.
> - The operation can either be "download" or "upload". The SSH command can be tweaked with the GIT_SSH or GIT_SSH_COMMAND environment variables.

So make sure a `git-lfs-authenticate` is part of the *default* PATH on the remote server, as illustrated in [`git-lfs/git-lfs` issue 2002](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2002#issuecomment-296688839).

Comment: Okay so  I'm understanding this so that I need to create a command that gives some info for the client but the documentation is REALLY vague on what to do. It says that the format is json but nothing else basically. What fields do I have to configure? How does the client get the info? Is it just reading the terminal output from a cat command and giving it to the client? Do I have to send an HTTP message to the client with the info?


I thought I was just gonna use the same SSH connection that I cloned with. Why do I need additional authentication when I'm already using SSH?

Comment: @Darkonode  My answer was just about the PATH on the remote server through SSH. The JSON part is managed by Git and Git LFS hook.

Comment: I'm really confused now. After reading a few more forum posts like this one
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4388 it really does seem like the command has no implementation for SSH and you need to create your own HTTP implementation instead. There just really is not enough information given to implement it. What I understand is that I need to generate a token to use data transfer over HTTP like said in https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1044#issuecomment-656354589 but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: @Darkonode Would [ksurent/git-lfs-authenticate](https://github.com/ksurent/git-lfs-authenticate) installed on the remote server be enough?

Comment: That's looking more promising. Also I did notice scrambling through the git-lfs repo that the pure SSH protocol should be available on the 3.0 release. I'm testing now whether git-lfs package through apt is actually different to that and I'm doing a new install through the homebrew link they've provided in their recent release.